# Android 7.0 Notification Sound from File Provider Uri not playing

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fileprovider, android-7.0-nougat

I'm changing my app code for supporting Android 7, but in my NotificationCompat.Builder.setSound(Uri) passing the Uri from FileProvider the Notification don't play any sound, in Android 6 using the Uri.fromFile() worked properly.

The mp3 file is in:

> /Animeflv/cache/.sounds/

This is my Notification Code:

> knf.animeflv.RequestBackground

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_not_r)
.setContentTitle(NotTit)
.setContentText(mess);
...
mBuilder.setVibrate(new long[]{100, 200, 100, 500});
mBuilder.setSound(UtilSound.getSoundUri(not)); //int
```

This is my UtilSound.getSoundUri(int)

```
public static Uri getSoundUri(int not) {
        switch (not) {
            case 0:
                return RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            default:
                try {
                    File file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Animeflv/cache/.sounds",getSoundsFileName(not));
                    if (file.exists()) {
                        file.setReadable(true,false);
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.N){
                            return FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "knf.animeflv.RequestsBackground",file);
                        }else {
                            return Uri.fromFile(file);
                        }
                    }else {
                        Log.d("Sound Uri","Not found");
                        return getSoundUri(0);
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return getSoundUri(0);
                }
        }
    }
```

In AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="knf.animeflv.RequestsBackground"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>
```

provider_paths.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="_.sounds" path="Animeflv/cache/.sounds/"/>
</paths>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39285228/how-to-set-audio-as-ringtone-programmatically-above-android-n?noredirect=1#comment66048598_39285228

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The following is from [a blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/09/07/notifications-sounds-android-7p0-aggravation.html) that I just published, reproduced here because, hey, why not?

---

You can put a custom ringtone on a `Notification`, via methods like
`setSound()` on `NotificationCompat.Builder`. This requires a `Uri`, and
that causes problems on Android 7.0, as is reported by
[a few people](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39359465/115145) on
[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39285228/how-to-set-audio-as-ringtone-programmatically-above-android-n?noredirect=1#comment66048508_39285228).

If you were using `file:` `Uri` values, they no longer work on Android 7.0
if your `targetSdkVersion` is 24 or higher, as the sound `Uri` is checked
for compliance with [the ban on `file:` `Uri` values](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/14/psa-file-scheme-ban-n-developer-preview.html).

However, if you try a `content:` `Uri` from, say, `FileProvider`, your
sound will not be played... because Android does not have read access to that
content.

Here are some options for addressing this.

**The Scalpel: `grantUriPermissions()`**

You can always grant permissions for content to other apps via `grantUriPermissions()`,
a method available on `Context`. The challenge is in knowing *who* to
grant the permissions to.

What works on a Nexus 6P (Android 6.0... still...) and a Nexus 9 (Android 7.0) is:

```
grantUriPermission("com.android.systemui", sound,
    Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

(where `sound` is the `Uri` that you are using with `setSound()`)

Whether this will hold up for all devices and all Android OS versions,
I cannot say.

**The Guillotine: No More User Files**

`android.resource` as a scheme works fine for `Uri` values for `setSound()`.
Instead of allowing users to choose their own ringtone from a file,
you only allow them to choose one of several ringtones that you ship
as raw resources in your app. If this represents a loss of app
functionality, though, your users may be unimpressed.

**The Axe: Use a Custom `ContentProvider`**

`FileProvider` cannot be used when it is exported — it crashes on
startup. However, for this case, the only `content:` `Uri` that will
work without other issues is one where the provider is `exported` and
has no read access permissions (or happens to require some permission that
`com.android.systemui` or the equivalent happens to hold).

Eventually, I'll add options for this to
[my `StreamProvider`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider), as
part of some "read only" provider functionality.

But, you could roll your own provider for this.

**The Chainsaw: Ban the Ban**

The following code snippet blocks all `StrictMode` checks related to
VM behavior (i.e., stuff other than main application thread behavior),
including the ban on `file:` `Uri` values:

```
StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder().build());
```

Alternatively, you could configure your own `VmPolicy` with whatever
rules you want, just without calling `detectFileUriExposure()`.

This allows you to use `file:` `Uri` values anywhere. There are good
reasons why Google is banning the `file:` `Uri`, and so trying to avoid
the ban may bite you in unfortunate body parts in the long term.

**The Nuke: Use a Lower `targetSdkVersion`**

This also removes the ban on `file:` `Uri` values, along with all other
behavior that a `targetSdkVersion` of 24+ opts into. Of note, this will
cause your app to display a "may not work with split-screen" `Toast`
if the user enters split-screen multi-window mode.

**The Real Solution: A Fix in Android**

The `NotificationManager` should be calling `grantUriPermissions()`
for us, or there should be some other way for us to associate
`FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` with the `Uri` that we use for custom
`Notification` sounds.
[Stay tuned for further developments](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=221899).

Comment: Thanks, The Scalpel was the answer!!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the thorough answer. To verify the robustness of the grantUriPermission solution ('The Scalpel'), I've tested it in different physical devices (including LG, Motorola, HTC, Samsung and Sony), from API 15 up to API 24. It works correctly on all of them, so the solution seems pretty solid (although certainly hacky).

Comment: @jmart: "although certainly hacky" -- absolutely. Using a read-only `ContentProvider` (see "The Axe") is the better answer. I'll probably rig up my `StreamProvider` such that if you mark it as exported, it treats everything as read-only, which would handle this problem fairly cleanly.

Comment: @CommonsWare where exactly are you calling grantUriPermission? Do you need to do it each time when building notifications, or would it be enough to grant permissions whenever the uri selection has changed?

Comment: @AllanW: AFAIK, for that scenario, you would only need to call `grantUriPermissions()` for each distinct `Uri` value. So, in your case, when the selection has changed. That being said, I doubt there is any harm in just calling `grantUriPermissions()` every time.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks. Do you also have any idea why not calling this seems to work for some devices? For instance, I have a OP3 on Nougat (on an Oxygen based rom), and it works fine for me. Same goes for my Nexus 5 on a custom rom with nougat. I've gotten a few reports from Crashlytics, and as you've mentioned, this error seems to only be reported by a few people.

Comment: @AllanW: No clue, sorry.

Comment: Seems like it should be fixed in Android P: https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/commit/2990141035d87028a7d31d8b0c3fbebc25fc2772

Comment: @CommonsWare can i set notification sound from apk expansion file?

Comment: @Pranav: I do not know, sorry.

Comment: Wouldn't StrictMode be disabled in production builds? I'm surprised that it's being run by the Google code even in release bits.

Comment: @fobbymaster: "Wouldn't StrictMode be disabled in production builds?" -- while you can do that, it won't help with Android 10. You might not have access to the file, and the code using the `Uri` might not have access to the file.

Comment: Sorry, let me rephrase - Why is StrictMode running on production builds at all without being disabled? Why do we have to disable it at all? Shouldn't it be already disabled?

Comment: @fobbymaster: I can't answer that, sorry.

Comment: @CommonsWare Just an update on this, it has finally been fixed as of September of last year.